# Is there a better way to achieve this with Linq or a better code

Tags: c#, linq

Let's say i have the following ordered by column ID DataTable  :

```
    ID    A    B
    -------------
    1    TT   12
    1    ZZ   12
    2    SS   11
    3    SS   15
    3    RR   27
```

My goal is to achieve this :

if there's any duplicate row with the same ID , i need to remove values from columns A and B.

Here's what i want to achieve based on my datatable :

```
ID   A    B
-----------
1    TT   12
1       
2    SS   11
3    SS   15
3  

    //here's the alogirithm that i have tried :

    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add("A", typeof(int));
    dt.Columns.Add("B", typeof(string));
    dt.Columns.Add("C", typeof(int));


    dt.Rows.Add(1, "TT",12);
    dt.Rows.Add(1, "ZZ",12);
    dt.Rows.Add(2, "SS",11);
    dt.Rows.Add(3, "SS",15);
    dt.Rows.Add(3, "RR", 27);

    int id1 = 0;
    int id2 = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        id1= (int)dt.Rows[i]["A"];
        for (int j = i + 1; j < dt.Rows.Count; j++)
        {
            id2 = (int)dt.Rows[j]["A"];
            if (id1 == id2) 
            {
                dt.Rows[j]["B"] = DBNull.Value;
                dt.Rows[j]["C"] = DBNull.Value;


            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: So if the row 1 and 2 have the same ID, you want to empty the other columns of row 2? Or empty both rows 1 and 2?

Comment: @Guilherme Yes , keep data on the first row ,and remove data from columns A and B and so on

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that one good way to do this is the following:

```
// group by the first column
var groupsOfDuplicates = dt.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().GroupBy(row => row[0]); 

// for each group
foreach (var groupOfDuplicateRows in groupsOfDuplicates)
{
    // Skip the first, let's just erase the others
    foreach (var duplicateRow in groupOfDuplicateRows.Skip(1))
    {
        duplicateRow[1] = DBNull.Value;
        duplicateRow[2] = DBNull.Value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
            dt.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(x => x["A"]).ToList().ForEach(myGroup =>
            myGroup.Skip(1).ToList().ForEach(myRow => { 
                                                        myRow["B"] = DBNull.Value;
                                                        myRow["C"] = DBNull.Value;
                                                      }));
```